# Shadow at the top of a Cell UITableCellView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, shadow

I wondered if anyone knows how to get a shadaow effect like the one in things as per the screenshot. To me it looks like the shadow effect is created by having a shadow at the bottom of the cell above and the top of the cell below.

I can create the one from the cell above using the code below but can't figure out how to do it on the cell underneath as it doesn't get shown it's as if the cells are rendered in reverse order in terms of the z-index.

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

CGFloat top = self.layer.bounds.origin.y;
CGFloat left = self.layer.bounds.origin.x;
CGFloat width = self.layer.bounds.size.width;

CGRect shadowFrame = CGRectMake(left, top, width, 44);
CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGPath;
self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

[Things http://www.purplesmash.com/images/Things.jpg](http://www.purplesmash.com/images/Things.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create hollow rectangle while drawing with CoreGraphics (align it exactly that hollow part cover your cell visible view) and set shadow for context - this will save performance for you.

**UPDATE:**
I've tried this inside my cell `drawRect:` method

```
// Creating path which will hold our hollow rectangle
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(-8.0f, -8.0f, 336.0f, 96.0f));
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(-5.0f, 0.0f, 330.0f, 80.0f));

// Saving current graphics context state
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// Configuring shadow
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f), 6.0f, 
                            [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

// Adding our path
CGContextAddPath(context, path);  

// Configure hollow rectangle fill color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

// Fill rectangle and keep hollow part transparent
CGContextEOFillPath(context);

// Restore graphics context
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Of course additional improvement will be pre-calculate `CGMutablePathRef path` somewhere in initialization or in this method by condition `if(path == NULL)`. Colors can be retained too. If this should be last row of your cell update, than maybe you don't event need to save context state.

Comment: Could you give an example, my method seems to run fine from a performance point of view but if you could elaborate and give a quick sample that would be great.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll try that when I'm at my dev PC later and update.

Comment: I guess my only concern with this approach is that I'm not sure if I can dynamically change the appearance of the cell once it's been drawn. In my app if the user taps the leftmost button the shadow is applied. If they tap it again it's removed. I don't have to reload the table it just acts on the cell. I guess I'll need to have a play some more.

Comment: When user taps on cell, you can redraw only it and this will be ok.

Comment: See above edit for how I implemented your suggestion, many thanks it's working as well as my previous code but hopefully more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do this by drawing the shadows as part of the checked cell instead of setting the shadow properties on the surrounding cells.

I'd do it by adding one or two CAGradientLayers as children of the checked cell's `contentView.layer`.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, do you have any sample code to give me a steer?

Comment: Ok I have followed that through and have it working. I'll post the code up a bit later :)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this in light of the suggestion from moonlight. I put that code into a method addInnerTopShadow when a cell needs that I call the method. I have added another method addInnerBottomShadow which puts in the shadow at the bottom.

I call these methods in the drawRect method and when I want to change between the states I call the method:

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

This allows me to toggle the state of the cell without doing things like

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

As the methods suggest I have outer shadow methods that put a shadow on the first and last cells but that's another issue and has been answered many times. I now have my app working exactly how I want. So thanks to Rob and Moonlight.

```
-(void)addInnerBottomShadow
{   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Creating path which will hold our hollow rectangle
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 44, 480, 80));
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 54, 480, 96));

    // Saving current graphics context state
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Configuring shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f), 6.0f, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    // Adding our path
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);  

    // Configure hollow rectangle fill color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // Fill rectangle and keep hollow part transparent
    CGContextEOFillPath(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, self.bounds);

    // Restore graphics context
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

-(void)addInnerTopShadow
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(-8.0f, -8.0f, 336.0f, 96.0f));
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(-5.0f, 0.0f, 330.0f, 80.0f));

    // Saving current graphics context state
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // Configuring shadow
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f), 7.0f, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    // Adding our path
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);  

    // Configure hollow rectangle fill color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    // Fill rectangle and keep hollow part transparent
    CGContextEOFillPath(context);
    CGContextClipToRect(context, self.bounds);

    // Restore graphics context
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```